# Features classification algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Assuming I have this array which show for each `fn`, *all possible features* it can have:

```
consts=
    [
    {
      name:'f1'
      possible_features:[a,d,c,b,h,k]
    },
    {
      name:'f2'
      possible_features:[a,b,f,g]
    }
    ]
```

and have this dic that show many(not all) possible `features` inputs and **required** outputs:

```
training = 
    [
    {
      output:'f1'
      input:[a,d]
    },
    {
      output:'f2'
      input:[a,g]
    }
    ]
```

This array have around 50-80 combinations(or "trainings"). where `a-z` are the features.

**I need to build a program that given consts+training create a rating array:**

```
rating = {a=100,b=65,c=85,d=45..} // 0-100 or 0-1000
```

so that given an input of `features` `[a,g,h,d]` , **I can rate each of** `consts`, to make a decision based on `training`, assuming `training` **will not be available**.

So for instance, for this given `rating`, and input `[a,b,d]` :

```
const_rating =
     f1=145 // winner!
     f2=100
```

Currently I created `rating` manually using an excel, but it grow, and I need an algorithm.

(I use `Python`)

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at some of the algorithms from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/). There's probably what you want somewhere in there. You might or might not want to preprocess the data with [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to automatically replace lists of categories `[a,d,c,b,h,k]` with 26-vectors `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: This might or might not be the kind of algorithm you want: [sklearn.feature_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#feature-selection)